# For some reason, printf function adds a space to what I want to display

Tags: c, printf

I'm trying to display text in columns, but on the second line of the output a space gets added. Am I doing anything wrong? (The entries do not contain a space before the string) Here are the functions involved:

```
add(List *book)
{
    Contact *runner = book->una;
    Contact *node = (Contact *) malloc(sizeof(Contact));

if (node == NULL);
else {
    printf("Add a contact\n");
    printf("Enter the first name: ");
    scanf("%s", node->fname);
    printf("Enter the last name: ");
    scanf("%s", node->lname);
    printf("Enter the mobile number: ");
    scanf("%s", node->number);
    printf("\nContact added!\n\n");
    node -> next = NULL;
    if(book->una == NULL){
        book->una = node;
    }
    else
    {
        while( runner->next != NULL)
        {
            runner = runner->next;
        }
        runner->next = node;
    }
}
}

    display(List *book)
{
    Contact *runner = book -> una;
    if(runner == NULL)
    {
        printf("%20s", "PHONEBOOK EMPTY!");
        return;
    }
    printf("Contact list\n");
    printf("%-15s%-15s%-15s", "First Name", "Last Name", "Mobile number\n");
    while( runner != NULL)
    {
        printf("%-15s%-15s%-15s\n", runner->fname, runner->lname, runner->number);
        runner = runner->next;
    }
}

/*An example output basically turns out like this:

First Name         Last Name         Mobile Number
 James              Harrison          123456
Wendy              Barnes            00000
Cam                Rodriguez         575938*/
```

Any input data will be printed as shown above.

Comment: The problem doesn't appear to be here.  Please update your question with a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should put the `\n` in the format string instead of the field. Since `Mobile number` has 13 characters, plus the `\n` 14 and one space is added as padding for the `%-15s`, it goes after the `\n` hence, in the next line.